# custom codeigniter library not returning data

Tags: codeigniter

I have made a codeigniter user login library but have run into a small issue. When I login it is not returning any of the functions in the library like `$this->get_user_username();`

On my dashboard I should be able to do this echo $this->user->get_user_username();

> **I think I know problem is because the if ($this->validate_password($password)) { is around the query. And stops
>   me returning any data.**

**Note:** I only would like to be able to set the user_id in session which is working. And just return the others as variables etc.

**Question** Because I am using `if ($this->validate_password($password)) {` in my login and once logged in it blocks me from retrieving any data what would be best solution so can still use it and retrieve my data

> With out setting it all in sessions as I said I only want user id set
>   in sessions.

**Dashboard Controller**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends MX_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('admin/user');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo $this->user->get_user_username();
        print_r($_SESSION);
        $data['top_navbar'] = Modules::run('admin/common/top_navbar/index');
        $data['column_left'] = Modules::run('admin/common/column_left/index');
        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

        $this->load->view('common/dashboard_view', $data);
    }
}
```

**User Library**

```
<?php

class User {

    private $user_id;
    private $username;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        if ($this->validate_password($password)) {

            $this->CI->db->where('username', $username);
            $user_query = $this->CI->db->get($this->CI->db->dbprefix . 'user');

            if ($user_query->num_rows() > 0) {

                $row = $user_query->row();

                $this->CI->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => $row->user_id)); // Working

                $this->user_id = $row->user_id;
                $this->user_group_id = $row->user_group_id;
                $this->username = $row->username;
                $this->firstname = $row->firstname;
                $this->lastname = $row->lastname;
                $this->email = $row->email;

                return true;

            } else {

                return false;   

            }

        } else {

            return false;
        }

    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->CI->session->unset_userdata('user_id');

        $this->user_id = '';
        $this->username = '';
    }

    public function get_user_id() {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    public function get_user_group_id() {
        return $this->user_group_id;
    }

    public function get_user_username() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function get_user_firstname() {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function get_user_lastname() {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function get_user_email() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function validate_password($password) {
        if (password_verify($password, $this->stored_hash())) {
            return $password;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function stored_hash() {
        $this->CI->db->where('username', $this->CI->input->post('username')); 
        $query = $this->CI->db->get($this->CI->db->dbprefix . 'user');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            return $row->password;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved I thought post my own answer, I had to add another section in the construct area of user library to make it work

And then use session userdata for where check.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();

    if ($this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') == TRUE) {

        $this->CI->db->where('user_id', $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id'));
        $user_query = $this->CI->db->get($this->CI->db->dbprefix . 'user');

        if ($user_query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $user_query->row();
            $this->user_id = $row->user_id;
            $this->user_group_id = $row->user_group_id;
            $this->username = $row->username;
            $this->firstname = $row->firstname;
            $this->lastname = $row->lastname;
            $this->email = $row->email;

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Library

```
<?php

class User {

    private $user_id;
    private $username;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        if ($this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') == TRUE) {

            $this->CI->db->where('user_id', $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id'));
            $user_query = $this->CI->db->get($this->CI->db->dbprefix . 'user');

            if ($user_query->num_rows() > 0) {

                $row = $user_query->row();

                $this->user_id = $row->user_id;
                $this->user_group_id = $row->user_group_id;
                $this->username = $row->username;
                $this->firstname = $row->firstname;
                $this->lastname = $row->lastname;
                $this->email = $row->email;

                return true;

            } else {

                return false;
            }

        } else {

            $this->logout();
        }
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        if ($this->validate_password($password)) {

            $this->CI->db->where('username', $username);
            $user_query = $this->CI->db->get($this->CI->db->dbprefix . 'user');

            if ($user_query->num_rows() > 0) {

                $row = $user_query->row();

                $this->CI->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => $row->user_id));

                $this->user_id = $row->user_id;
                $this->user_group_id = $row->user_group_id;
                $this->username = $row->username;
                $this->firstname = $row->firstname;
                $this->lastname = $row->lastname;
                $this->email = $row->email;

                return true;

            } else {

                return false;   

            }

        } else {

            return false;
        }

    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->CI->session->unset_userdata('user_id');

        $this->user_id = '';
        $this->username = '';
    }

    public function get_user_id() {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    public function get_user_group_id() {
        return $this->user_group_id;
    }

    public function get_user_username() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function get_user_firstname() {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function get_user_lastname() {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function get_user_email() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function validate_password($password) {
        if (password_verify($password, $this->stored_hash())) {
            return $password;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function stored_hash() {
        $this->CI->db->where('username', $this->CI->input->post('username')); 
        $query = $this->CI->db->get($this->CI->db->dbprefix . 'user');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            return $row->password;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```